# how to make open link in new tab in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Blogger, how make a link open in new tab!?

I'm using a normal free template with few pages

i need to know how to open the respective link in new tab when clicked on its respective text.

For ex, I clicked on the page name "Our Service" on my website then it should open link-10: `examplee.com` in a new tab

I've tried using `target='_blank'` but it doesn't work for me.
here is the code:-

```
    <b:widget id='LinkList210' locked='true' title='Menu' type='LinkList' 
  version='1'>
        <b:widget-settings>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-9'>Documentation</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-9'>http://www.example.com</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-8'> Services</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-7'>http://example.com</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-8'>http://www.example.com</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-10'>our services</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-5'>http:example</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-6'>http://www.example.com</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-3'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-4'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-1'>_Multi Dropdown</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-0'>Features</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-3'>__Dropdown 2</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-2'>__Dropdown 1</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-5'>_ShortCodes</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-4'>__Dropdown 3</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-7'>_Error Page</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-6'>_SiteMap</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>NONE</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-1'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-2'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-0'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-10'>http://examplee.com/</b:widget-setting>
        </b:widget-settings>
        <b:includable id='main'>
        <div class='widget-content'>
          <ul itemscope='' itemtype='http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement'> 
            <li><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' target='_blank'>Home</a></li>
            <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
              <li itemprop='name'><a expr:href='data:link.target' itemprop='url' target='_blank'> <data:link.name/></a></li>
            </b:loop>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </b:includable>
      </b:widget>
```

Comment: exp:target='_blank',  is a simple idea in base of your html of blogger

Answer (score 2):

You can use it to get link in new tab in blogger

```html
 <a href="#" onClick="window.open('index.html','_blanck')">open in new tab</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way: To make internal page (*_self*) links, create a **PageList**. For links you want to open in a new tab/window (*_blank*), create a **LinkList** and go to your template/edit html. Click on Jump To Widget and select the LinkList. You will see something like this:

```
<b:widget id='LinkList1' locked='false' title='Our Channels' type='LinkList' version='1'>
<b:widget-settings>
<b:widget-setting name='text-0'>Facebook</b:widget-setting>
<b:widget-setting name='link-0'>https://facebook.com/yourpage</b:widget-settings> 
<b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'><h2><data:title/></h2></b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <ul>
      <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
      <li><a expr:href='data:link.target'><data:link.name/></a></li>
 </b:loop>
```

Now, go to the 'li' part, and add target='_blank' . Like this:

```
<li><a expr:href='data:link.target' target='_blank'><data:link.name/></a></li>
```

Done! All links from this link list will open in a new tab/window.